# How to observe sensor values with app on background?

Tags: ios, swift, background

I'm developing an API to help developers to build context aware applications, but I've become stuck in one problem, how to monitor sensor data with app on background.

I would like to be able to **generate notifications when a sensor change to a determined value or range**.

**Example : Trigger a notification when the user brightness reach 60%**

Something that is already implemented with the didEnterRegion on the CLLocation framework.

Android has that on the https://developers.google.com/awareness/, I would like to do something like the Fence API.

Does anyone knows how to better approach this problem?

Comment: Apple don’t allow background process executions. Only specific event gives you window to execute some code. Such as location change.

Comment: What are these “sensors”?  How do you connect to them? Are they Bluetooth low energy devices?

Comment: The sensors are the built in sensors, like Proximity sensor, Motion sensor, Gyroscope, etc